# How do I make a program that mimics Kafka operations?

Tags: api, apache-kafka, architecture, publish-subscribe

As part of my big data course in university, I'm required to mimic kafka. It involves setting up a mini-Kafka on a student's system, complete with a Producer, Subscriber and a Publish-Subscribe architecture.

High-Level Overview

> You are required to set up a mini-Zookeeper, multiple Kafka Brokers, one of which is a leader, and multiple Producers and Consumers.
> The number of Producers and Consumers must be dynamic and not hard-coded, i.e.,the user must be able to specify the number of Producers and Consumers.
> The number of topics must also be dynamic, the user should be able to create and delete topics on demand.
> To help you get started with the project, the following sections will provide a detailed description of all the individual modules.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/582I9.png)

Comment: A simple solution will be to write an API-based system. Which will trigger these commands, you can either go with the console (Shortest way possible)

Comment: @bananas Can you elaborate more? My peers are suggesting to use socket programming on python to mimic producers and consumers. We're clueless on how to build a zookeeper though.

Comment: Sounds great, but this is off-topic as too-broad for Stackoverflow. Refer [help] on asking homework questions and what is on-topic. Kafka itself doesn't need Zookeeper anymore, so your instructions are outdated, btw. The suggestion of Python is fine; look at ZeroMQ.